How do I use C++ modules with an opencv project and Cmake?
I am trying to start a C++ 20 project with opencv and want to use modules instead of the normal .hpp files.
When I run the build command make I get the error:
Hello: error: failed to read compiled module: No such file or directory
Hello: note: compiled module file is ‘gcm.cache/Hello.gcm’
Hello: note: imports must be built before being imported
Hello: fatal error: returning to the gate for a mechanical issue
compilation terminated.

I'm confused by this since there is no gcm.cache anywhere. I tried doing a project using modules without opencv and gcm.cache/Hello.gcm populated in the main directory.
Also, the project compiles fine without using import and removing .cppm files.
My main.cpp file is (this is copied from the opencv tutorial:
#include <cstdio>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>

import Hello;

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    hello();
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR );

    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}

The module I am trying to import is Hello.cppm:
module;         

#include <iostream>

export void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}

My CmakeLists.txt file is:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(modality)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fmodules-ts")

add_executable(modality main.cpp
        modules/chemistry/coppersulfate.cpp
        Hello.cppm
)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
target_link_libraries( modality ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

I've tried adding different set() settings like set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fmodules-ts")  to no avail.

does this require OpenCV to "play along" with this new C++ feature you want to use?

Stack Overflow already has questions about C++ modules in CMake. Have you checked them and their answers? E.g. that one, which suggests to use target_sources(.. FILES_SET .. TYPE CXX_MODULES).

@Tsyvarev thank you that solved my problem. I didn't know the CLion IDE automatically bundles CMake 3.27 (at least on linux). That hung me up more than anything. I also spent some time searching around for GCC 14 before realizing, afaik, it hasn't been released yet so I had to switch to clang.
